# apply a lambda function to a dask dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I am looking to apply a `lambda` function to a dask dataframe to change the lables in a column if its less than a certain percentage. The method that I am using works well for a pandas dataframe but the same code does not work for dask  a dataframe. The code is below.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['ant','ant','cherry', 'bee', 'ant'], 'B':['cat','peach', 'cat', 'cat', 'peach'], 'C':['dog','dog','roo', 'emu', 'emu']})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

df:
```

output:

```py
     A     B      C
0   ant    cat   dog
1   ant    peach dog
2   cherry cat   roo
3   bee    cat   emu
4   ant    peach emu
```

```py
ddf.compute()
```

output:

```py
     A     B      C
0   ant    cat   dog
1   ant    peach dog
2   cherry cat   roo
3   bee    cat   emu
4   ant    peach emu
```

```py
list_ = ['B','C']
df.apply(lambda x: x.mask(x.map(x.value_counts(normalize=True))<.5, 'other') if x.name not in list_ else x)
```

output:

```py
     A     B      C
0   ant    cat   dog
1   ant    peach dog
2   other  cat   roo
3   other  cat   emu
4   ant    peach emu
```

Do the same for dask dataframe:

```py
ddf.apply(lambda x: x.mask(x.map(x.value_counts(normalize=True))<.5, 'other') if x.name not in list_ else x,axis=1).compute()
```

output(gives warning and not the output required):

```py
/home/michael/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py:3107: UserWarning: `meta` is not specified, inferred from partial data. Please provide `meta` if the result is unexpected.
  Before: .apply(func)
  After:  .apply(func, meta={'x': 'f8', 'y': 'f8'}) for dataframe result
  or:     .apply(func, meta=('x', 'f8'))            for series result
  warnings.warn(msg)
      A       B       C
0   other   other   other
1   other   other   other
2   other   other   other
3   other   other   other
4   other   other   other
```

Could someone be able to help me out to get the required output for the dask dataframe instance.

Thanks

Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not performing the same thing in the pandas and dask cases: for the latter you have `axis=1`, so you end up replacing any value which occurs less than twice in a given **row**, which is all of them.

If you change to `axis=0`, you will see that you get an exception. This is because to compute, say, the first partition, you would need the whole dataframe also to be passed to the lambda function - else how could you get the value_counts?

The solution to your problem would be to get the value counts separately. You could explicitly compute this (the result is small) or pass it to the lambda. Note furthermore that going this path means you can avoid using `apply` in favour of `map` and making things more explicit. Here I am exclusively picking the one column, you could loop.

```
vc = ddf.A.value_counts().compute()
vc /= vc.sum()  # because dask's value_count doesn't normalise

def simple_map(df):
    df['A'] = df['A'].map(lambda x: x if vc[x] > 0.5 else 'other')
    return df

ddf.map_partitions(simple_map, meta=df[:0]).compute()
```

Comment: Hi @mdurant, I would like to do it without using the pandas dataframe (df). Thanks

Comment: When you have something that works, I say stick with it. The procedure you are after seems to me to require two passes through the data.

Comment: ```for c in list1:
    vc = ddf[c].value_counts().compute()
    vc /= vc.sum()
    print(vc)
    for i in range(vc.count()):
        if vc[i]<0.5:
            ddf[c] = ddf[c].where(ddf[c] != vc.index[i], 'others')
    print(ddf.compute())```

Comment: You've lost me. You may want to submit a new, more specific question.